# $gx=gy$ iff $x=y$ group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let group $G$ act on set $X$, let $g \in G$ and $x,y \in X$. Is it true that $gx=gy$ iff $x=y$? I doubt that since group action is function $f(g,x)=gx$ and I think in order to be true function has to be injective. If not, is it true if action is double transitive? (Last question is because I read some pdf about double transitive group actions and author use $gx=gy$ iff $x=y$.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this hasn't been answered here before . . .

Comment: $g$ acts as a permutation. Permutations are bijections. So $gx=gy$ iff $x=y$, with "if" because it's a function, and "only if" because it is a bijection.

Comment: Summary : If $\phi:G\times X\to X$ be a group action, then for each fixed $g\in G$ , $\phi_{g}:X\to X$ is a bijection i.e $\phi_g\in \textrm{Symm}(X) $

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x,y\in X$ and $g\in G$.

One direction is clear but subtle: group actions are functions by definition and are thus *well-defined*, meaning $x=y$ implies $g\cdot x=g\cdot y$.

We use this for the other direction. Suppose $g\cdot x=g\cdot y$. This gives

$$\begin{align}
x&\stackrel{(1)}{=}e\cdot x\\
&=(g^{-1}g)\cdot x\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot x)\\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=}g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot y)\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}(g^{-1}g)\cdot y\\
&=e\cdot y\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}y.
\end{align}$$

Here the equalities marked $(1)$ hold by the identity property of a group action. Those marked by $(2)$ hold because of the associativity property of a group action. Finally, $(3)$ is true by well-definedness.